# Can't get my monitor refresh rate @ 144hz to work HELP!

Tags: monitor

[sudo] password for tjk:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 595mm x 336mm
   1920x1080      60.0 +  144.0  
   1680x1050     120.0*    60.0  
   1280x1024     120.0     75.0     60.0  
   1440x900      120.0     59.9  
   1024x768      120.0     75.1     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

as you can see im using 1680x1060 @ 120hz but if i try to use 1920x1080 @ 144hz the screen goes black and so signal!!!!

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144.0  DONT WORK
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144    DONT WORK
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 120.0  DONT WORK
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 120    DONT WORK
```

Why is that 1680x1050 works fine @120hz and not my  high resolution 1920x1080???

Comment: You *GPU* supports 1920x1080 at 60 and 144 hz (not at 120).  What does your *monitor* support?

Comment: my monitor support 144 and 120 i tested both at 1920x1080

Comment: OK, but xrandr is reporting that it does not know how to do 1920x1080 @ 120 hz, and your monitor seems to 'turn off'  @ 144hz.

Comment: yes my monitor turns off 1920x1080 @ 144 hz. I have a gaming monitor and yes it does support 1920x1080 @ 144 hz but not in linux it looks like. It works at 1680X1050 @ 120 hz fine but i want to make it work in 1920x1080 @ 144hz :(